# How to pass dynamic _id value in mongo collection.findOne() using meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My _id value is coming from iron-router.

My code:

```
Template.template_name.helpers({
    'edit': function () {
        var id = Router.current().params._id;
        return Collection.find.One({ _id: id});
    }
});
```

The above code does not work.

Comment: How does it not work? Please explain what behaviour you are facing, and tell us if you get any error. See what is a [mcve].

Comment: You have a typo in your code at `Collection.find.One({ _id: id})`. You need to rewrite that to `Collection.findOne({ _id: id})`

Comment: @Kyll var id is getting the value but Collection.findOne({_id: id}) is not considering the id value and is giving undefined. how to fix it??

Answer (score 0):

First check id returns correctly or not with alert or console.

```
Template.template_name.helpers({
'edit': function () {
    var id = Router.current().params._id;
    alert(id);
    return Collection.find({ _id: id});
  } 
});
```

And in router you have to pass like this:

```
Router.route('/template/:_id', {
 name: 'template',
 template: 'template',
});
```

Comment: Yes router is returning id and id is also getting the correct value and everything is well with router, the only problem is Collection.find() is not accepting id value so this  needs to be fixed. If i pass a static value instead of id then it works but i need to send dynamic value.

Comment: can you tell me type of id means object or string

Comment: Please checkout id  value and database value both data types are equal or not

Comment: id value is a number means 1,2 and so on, its not the objectId which mongo generally uses. so this id is creating problems for me.

Comment: then why you are using  `Router.current().params._id;`  _id mens objectId it should be string or object.if you write your own function then only it generate different data type. can you show your database _id value example.

Comment: I used MongoInt32() when i converted to Mongodb from Mysql. But still not able to figure out why Collection.find() is not accepting _id dynamically and Router.current().params._id is returning the correct value.

Comment: I think it's an issue about datatypes please checkout once if returns value  and database storing value are same datatype or not